# Display validation errors in a div with extjs4

Tags: extjs

I'm trying to add validations for a form (which has few mandatary fields and few alpha only and max length validation). I need to display the error messages(how many it might be) in the top left of the form where I have a div with an ID. I'm not sure were to start with as this would be my first try for validation. Could any one post a simple example or any example in the net (I had searched a lot but not able to find anything that match my need) so that I can start with...Pls help...

Comment: Has done it in my own way somehow...Placed a label instead of div and has set the text of the lable with the error message as `Ext.getCmp('errorID').setText("Error: Gender is Required");`...not sure if this is the best thing to do...Anyways..it works...

Comment: Yeah this is a correct way of doing it. Anyway I wouldn't use Ext.getCmp but I'd query my component with up and down methods. Unless you can only have one instance of your form open at once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Links you may read :

- [Ext.form.Basic](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic)
- [Ext.form.field.Field getErrors method](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Field-method-getErrors)
- [Advanced Validation Examples Using VTypes](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/form/adv-vtypes.html)

An example of what you can do with this ([live example here](http://jsfiddle.net/SYsXx/1/)) :

```
var errors = [];
var fields = form.getFields(); // form : Ext.form.Basic
var errorsTpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<ul><tpl for="."><li>{field} : {error}</li></tpl></ul>'
);
fields.each(function (field) {
    errors = errors.concat(Ext.Array.map(field.getErrors(), function (error) {
        return { field: field.getName(), error: error }
    }));
});
errorsTpl.overwrite('myOutputDiv', errors);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.
Thanks @procrastinator